# Rotary wheel does not show the effect of ease In and ease Out

Tags: ios, animation

I have used the follwing code to rotate a wheel with 26 segments.The problem is that it is not showing the effect of easeIn and ease Out.

```
- (void) spinWithOptions: (UIViewAnimationOptions) options {
   // this spin completes 360 degrees every 2 seconds
   [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5f
                         delay: 0.0f
                       options: options
                    animations: ^{
                       self.imageToMove.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageToMove.transform, M_PI_2/6.49);
                    }
                    completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                       if (finished) {
                          if (animating) {
                             // if flag still set, keep spinning with constant speed
                             [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                          } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                             // one last spin, with deceleration
                             [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                          }
                       }
                    }];
}

- (void) startSpin {
   if (!animating) {
      animating = YES;
      [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
   }   
}

- (void) stopSpin {
    // set the flag to stop spinning after one last 90 degree increment
    animating = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `EaseIn` causes the animation to begin slowly and then speed up, this should happen only on first animation which is 0.5 sec, afterwards you use `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` and only for last animation you use `EastOut`.

As far as I can see code looks ok, are you sure you can see `EaseIn` effect in such a short time? Try to set longer duration and see does effect occur.

Comment: If i keep 0.9 sec or any other longer duration then the my wheel rotates very slowly. So is there any solution by which the speed is fast and ease in and ease out effect is shown

Comment: @Jane set longer duration only for ease in and out? before UIView animateWithDuration define some var duration, set it to 2 (or whatever you like) when options == UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn or UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut, otherwise it'll be 0.5